# How can I get rid of namespace in Asp.Net MVC for each loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was referring to one of the examples and on it's aspx pages, this code is written:

```
<% foreach (KandaAlpha.Domain.Model.Entities.Customer customer in (List<KandaAlpha.Domain.Model.Entities.Customer>)(ViewData["Customers"]))
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= customer.CustomerID%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=customer.FullName%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=customer.LastUpdatedOn.ToString()%>
        </td>        
    </tr>
    <% } %>
```

How can I write `KandaAlpha.Domain.Model.Entities.Customer` to just Customer? Where should I write import namespace code?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using an `<%@ Import` statement in the beginning of your view:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="KandaAlpha.Domain.Model.Entities" %>
```

Or by adding the namespace to the `<namespaces>` section of your web.config and in this case it will be global for all views:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="KandaAlpha.Domain.Model.Entities"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Or the best way and the one which I would recommend you to is to get rid of ViewData and use view models and display templates. In this case your entire `foreach` loop will disappear and would be replaced by the following one liner:

```
<table>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers) %>
</table>
```

and then inside the corresponding display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Customer.ascx`) define the template of a customer which will be rendered for each element of your view model's `Customers` collection:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Customer>" 
%>
<tr>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CustomerID) %></td>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FullName) %></td>
    <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.LastUpdatedOn) %></td>
</tr>
```

Also notice the usage of `Html.DisplayFor` because if your customer FullName is `<script>alert('I hacked you');</script>` you might get into trouble as you are not HTML encoding it.

As you can see once we get rid of `ViewData` and start using view models which is what I always recommend our views become really simple and readable.

Comment: Is this special folder: `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/`? Like other magic folders i.e Controllers, Models etc?

Comment: @Bob: Yes, it's convention-based. You can have display templates either there, or in ~/Views/YourController/DisplayTemplates/, and there are equivalent conventions for editor templates (just switch "Display" for "Editor" everywhere...)

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger, yes it is special. You could also use `~/Views/YourControllerName/DisplayTemplates` which is where ASP.NET MVC first looks for a template and if it doesn't find one it goes to the Shared folder. Could be useful for templates that are only valid for a given controller.

Comment: @Darin: Seeing your quality of answer I thought I should visit and read your blog entries but I found this type of stuff "Les projets précédents ont été redécoupés afin de fo". Please write something that we all can understand and follow. Really I did not understand what you meant by that encrypted line.

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger, it's in French :-) There are some articles written by a colleague of mine who prefers French. I write in English.

Comment: @Darin: Ok. I couldn't even make out which language it was :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Themes/Whatever/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Whatever.ViewModels.MyViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="KandaAlpha.Domain.Model.Entities" %>
<%= //content %>
```